# What is the difference between require with curly braces and require normal?

Tags: node.js

What is the difference between this

```
const authController = require("../controller/authController");
```

and this

```
const { authController } = require("../controller/authController");
```

my code doesnt work when i call a function like authController.createUser in second one and i wondered thats why?

Thanks for helps.

Comment: mind you read Destructuring assignment

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

The difference between example one and example two is that you are using the [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) method in example two. That means, you can destruct an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), or [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to have the keys of the object as variables.

So, for example if we take this simple object and we start destructuring:

```js
const someObject = {
    something1: "1",
    something2: "2",
    something3: "3",
    something4: "4",

};

const { something1 } = someObject;
console.log(something1) // Returns 1
```

You see that we can use `something1` as a "new variable" instead of accessing it by using `someObject.something1`.

In your case you are including a module / class with the name `authController`, but if your module doesn't have a method or key called `authController`, using the following method:

```js
const { AuthController } = ...
```

won't work, because it's unable to access this method or key.

So, the first one: `authController.createUser()` will work because you are loading up the entire module without destructuring the module. If you do something like this `const { createUser } = require("authController")`, you can use it like `createUser(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Difference between

```
const authController = require("../controller/authController");
```

and

```
const { authController } = require("../controller/authController");
```

is, when your module exported by default from your .js file we use first syntax, while if there are several modules getting exported from a single .js file we use the second syntax. Also you cannot have more than one default export from a file. Hope that helps.